# Return only image tag from gcloud

Tags: docker, gcloud, cicd, google-artifact-registry

I am trying to set up automated versioning in my CI/CD pipeline using gcloud. I want to get the most recent docker image version and return it's tag value so I can programmatically update my version tags within my pipeline.

I am currently running:

```
gcloud artifacts docker images list <LOCATION>-docker.pkg.dev/<PROJECT-ID>/<REPO>/<IMAGE> \
--include-tags \
--sort-by=~update_time \ 
--limit=1 \
--format='value(tags)' \
```

I get the following return:

Listing items under project, location, repository.

0.25

The command is returning to me the tag I am looking for, but it includes the extra string before that I want to remove. I have tried a combination of awk, sep, grep, cut, and jq commands to remove that descriptive string, but I cannot remove it.

How can I go about getting the most recent version tag from a docker image in my artifact repository so I can automate my versioning?

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you find any solution?